# basic recursive backtracking (robot 2D pathfinding)

Tags: java

I'm working on a practice problem and is stuck. The problem asks to write a method that takes in two integers x and y to print all solutions for traveling in the 2D plane from (0,0) to (x,y) by repeatedly using one of three moves:

- move right 1 (E)
- move up 1 (N)
- move right 1 and up 1 (NE)

These are some example calls:

- call: travel(2, 1)
- output: E E N // E N E // E NE // N E E // NE E

I wrote the following code:

```
public void travel(int x, int y) {
    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    } else if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
        System.out.print("E ");
        travel(x-1, y);
        System.out.print("N ");
        travel(x, y-1);
        System.out.print("NE ");
        travel(x-1, y-1);
    } else if (x > 0 && y == 0) {
        System.out.print("E ");
        travel(x-1, y);
    } else if (y > 0 && x == 0) {
        System.out.print("N ");
        travel(x, y-1);
    }
}
```

Calling the above method results in the following code:

- call: travel(2,1);
- output: E E N // N E // NE // N E E // NE E

I know that for this example call the problem lies with the E only getting printed once for three different cases that require E because the E is printed before the subsequent recursive methods are called.

I would like to fix this (without certainty that this is the right approach) by attaching the System.out.print command with each calling of the travel method. That way whenever travel method is called the result is printed with the first letter every time. However, since the method doesn't return anything, I can't insert the method within the print statement. This is where I've been stuck for a long time.

Any advice on how to go from here would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm; you know, flatbed pen plotters used to have that problem -- how do you find the optimum solution to moving a pen from point A to point B? I seem to recall there was a paper on that subject once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When recursively building solutions, it's common to pass a partially built solution as an argument to the recursive call.

```
public void travel(int x, int y, String path) {
    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        System.out.println(path);
    } else if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
        travel(x-1, y, path + ' E');
        travel(x, y-1, path + ' N');
        travel(x-1, y-1, path + ' NE');
    } else if (x > 0 && y == 0) {
        travel(x-1, y, path + ' E');
    } else if (y > 0 && x == 0) {
        travel(x, y-1, path + ' N');
    }
}
```

See how we build the path as we go along - and let the function calls handle the complexity of remembering where we are in the search? This also has the nice property of simplifying our code, since we get exactly one call to `System.out.println` per path.